# Eclipse-CDT: Automatic Path Discovery when cross-compiling for Linux under Windows

Tags: c++, windows, eclipse, cross-platform, eclipse-cdt

I'm using Eclipse-CDT to develop and compile projects for Linux. As host both Linux or Windows may be used.

The project is created as Makefile project with a special build command, so I changed the build-command from `make` to our special one and the "Build" and "Clean" commandline approbriately. The build command uses a gcc from a directory not in `$PATH`, because the whole compiler-suite is located in the version control system. (Correct `$PATH` is set by the build command.)

This works fine under Linux: Eclipse learns the Symbols and Include Files automatically.
However, under Windows the Symbols are recognized, but the Include Paths aren't.

When I have a look in the generated MyProject.sc file in the `workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.cdt.make.core` directory, I see that the Include-Files are recognized, but prepended with a `C:\cygwin`.

The GCC command line uses absolute paths without the Drive letter.
(The whole source tree is located on a special Drive (e.g. `W:`), CWD is on this drive ).
E.g. `gcc`/`g++` is invoked with `-I /net_libs/lib1/inc` and Eclipse recognizes `C:\cygwin\net_libs\lib1\inc`.

BTW: The standard-include paths are recognized correctly (e.g. `W:/toolchain/win32/i686-pc-linux-gnu/include/c++/4.2.1`).

The Build-Directory is set to the directory of the Makefile which is on the same Drive as the Sources and Includes.

I tried various "Toolchain" settings (Cygwin, MinGw, Linux gcc), the result is same every time. (After changing the settings, I even stopped Eclipse, deleted the sc file and started Eclipse again).

I don't know why Eclipse knows about my Cygwin installation in C:\Cygwin - the installation is NOT used by the compiler or related tools.

When I change the .sc file manually and correct the paths and restart Eclipse, everything works fine.

Do you have any hints what may be the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at Project->Propterties->C/C++ Build->Discovery Options.
There is a **Compiler invocation command** - usually set to `gcc`, which means "gcc in PATH". Try setting this to your gcc from your build system.

Comment: This option is only used to get the standard-include-paths - it is set to my toolchain-compiler and discovery works fine, these paths are recognized correctly.

I think my problem has something to do with the (Cygwin) path mapping. I tried again on a Windows-PC where no Cygwin is installed and there Eclipse does not map / to C:\Cygwin - instead of this it does no mapping it all - and so does not recognize the include paths, too.